# How to get the last 5-10 message from a database?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am gtting data from database, but it's printed again and again. There is get coding of index page.

```
var lastmsgid = 0;
function getChat() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "view_msg.php",
        data: "sid=<?php echo $id; ?>&lastmsgid="+lastmsgid,
        async: false,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(rows) {
            for (var i in rows) {
                var row = rows[i];
                var uname=row['uname'];
                var msg=row['msg'];
                $('#chatbox').append("<b>"+uname+"</b> : </b>"+msg).append("<hr />");
                lastmsgid=row['id'];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is my `view_msg.php` page:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    require_once('include/util.php');
    $sid = $_POST['sid'];
    $lastmsgid = $_POST['lastmsgid'];
    $sql = "SELECT m.`id`, m.`msg`, u.`uname` FROM `message` as m JOIN `userdata` as u ON (m.`senderid`=u.`id`) WHERE  m.`rcvrid` = ".$_SESSION['id']." OR m.`rcvrid` =$sid AND `senderid` = $sid OR `senderid` =".$_SESSION['id']." AND m.`id` > $lastmsgid order by m.`id` DESC limit 0,2" ;
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    if (!empty($data)) {
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    exit;
?>
```

Comment: `limit` with `order by`

Comment: @tomexsans did you read his code at all?

Comment: This question has tons to do with jQuery

Comment: `async:false` is bad, and you don't even need it. So, why did you add it?

Comment: `mysql_` is deprecated. Use `mysqli_` with prepared statements or PDO.

Comment: My `lastmsgid` is ``; DROP TABLE `message`; --``. Please be more careful the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your SQL query.. You need to use brackets in where condition because you are using OR.. I don't know the conditions for your desired result but it may be like below:

```
$sql="SELECT m.`id`,m.`msg`,u.`uname` FROM `message` as m JOIN `userdata` as u ON (m.`senderid`=u.`id`) WHERE  ((m.`rcvrid` = ".$_SESSION['id']." OR m.`rcvrid` =$sid) AND (`senderid` = $sid OR `senderid` =".$_SESSION['id']." ) ) AND m.`id` > $lastmsgid order by m.`id` DESC limit 0,2" ;
```

Comment: setInterval(function(){getChat();},3000); I have used setinterval i have used your query now its printing only 2 time so plz think again and told me wht to do rightnow

Comment: Here is an good example of ajax chat application.. You should use ajax long pooling for that.. 
http://portal.bluejack.binus.ac.id/tutorials/webchatapplicationusinglong-pollingtechnologywithphpandajax